# Why is the HTML-Code not rendered when I use a custom angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML:

```
<section>
     <!-- <div ng-controller="Ctrl"> -->
     <div nt-attr-dir></div>
</section>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .directive('ntAttrDir', function factory() {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
      template: "<div> Test </div>",
      replace:false,
      restrict:"A"
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
  });
```

So expected result is the html-code should look like

```
<section>
 <!-- <div ng-controller="Ctrl"> -->
     <div nt-attr-dir><div> Test </div></div>
</section>
```

But it looks always as below

```
<section>
 <!-- <div ng-controller="Ctrl"> -->
     <div nt-attr-dir></div>
</section>
```

What am I missing so that  Test is not being displayed.

Comment: Any console errors Angular throws? Your element should have `class="ng-scope"` if the bindings are working. Put a jsFiddle up if not and we can debug.

Comment: You do have `ng-app="docsSimpleDirective"` directive , don't you?

Comment: Your HTML code looks like as it is. However, your DOM should look like what you expect it to be. Don't you see Test being rendered in the browser?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ruetzi/Zn7sG/, Test is shown in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The only thing I can think of is the `ng-app` directive missing:

```
<html ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
```

#### Why?

- This directive is 100% valid.
- I Assume there is no hidden error in the console which wasn't reported.